# Build se tranca en Genexus 16 U11

Tags: genexus

Estoy usando Genexus 16 U11 Build 147071.

Cuando hago un Build o Rebuild, queda colgado completamente en algunas especificaciones o generando algún Js, genexus no se tranca, pero el build no continua. Pensé que era el Antivirus, pero desactivándolo sigue pasando lo mismo.

Antes usaba Genexus 16 U6 y no tenía problemas para hacer build.

Ejemplo:

```
Specifying ViewxmlWorkList ...
Generating to Preproduccion\web\com\informes\wwregion.java
Generating to Preproduccion\web\com\informes\wwregion_impl.java
Generating to Preproduccion\web\wwregion.js
Generating to Preproduccion\web\com\informes\viewxmlworklist.java
Generating to Preproduccion\web\com\informes\viewxmlworklist_impl.java
Generating to Preproduccion\web\viewxmlworklist.js
Specifying WWxmlWorkList ...
```

Queda colgado en el Specifying WWxmlWorkList ...

¿Alguna idea de que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: te pasa siempre en cualquier kb ? o solo con una especifica? probaria de borrar todo lo generado y hacer rebuild si es en una kb especifica.

Comment: Aparentemente es un bug. (Por si la respuesta de OP termina borrada).

Answer (score 0):

Al final era un Bug de Genexus 16 U11 y ya quedó reportado.

Comment: Este tipo de bugs son molestos. ¿Tienes un enlace al reporte? Por si otro usuario se encuentra con el mismo problema, podría usarlo como referencia para ver el estado en el que se encuentra la incidencia.